# building a python abc interface with a base class that derives from a built-in type

Tags: python, abc

I would like to build an interface whose base class derives from a python built-in type such a dict. To do so, I use the python `abc` of the standard library but when I run the following test, no exception is raised for the missing method in the concrete class implementation.

```
import abc

class Base(dict):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def toto(self):
        pass

class Concrete(Base):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Concrete()
```

If class `Base` derives now from `object` instead of `dict`, the expected `abc` mechanism works. Would you have any idea about the reason of this behaviour ? Is it something expected and if so how to circumvent this ?

Comment: The same notes apply there; `ABCMeta.__new__` sets a `class.__abstractmethods__` attribute (a `frozenset()`) containing what methods are abstract on that specific class, so for `Concrete` the attribute is set to `frozenset(['toto'])`. When creating an instance of `Concrete`, the `Concrete.__new__` method, as inherited from `object.__new__`, is supposed to check that attribute and raise an exception if it is not empty. But `dict.__new__` is in the way here and the exception is never raised.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and also for the matching link that I missed